# practical usage of /etc/networks file

Tags: linux, networking, hosts, standard

What is the practical usage of `/etc/networks` file? As I understand, one can give names to networks in this file. For example:

```
root@fw-test:~# cat /etc/networks
default         0.0.0.0
loopback        127.0.0.0
link-local      169.254.0.0
google-dns      8.8.4.4
root@fw-test:~#
```

However, if I try to use this network name for example in `ip` utility, it does not work:

```
root@fw-test:~# ip route add google-dns via 104.236.63.1 dev eth0
Error: an inet prefix is expected rather than "google-dns".
root@fw-test:~# ip route add 8.8.4.4 via 104.236.64.1 dev eth0
root@fw-test:~#
```

What is the practical usage of `/etc/networks` file?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As written in the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/networks.5.html), the `/etc/networks` file is to describe symbolic names for networks. With network, it is meant the network address with tailing `.0` at the end. Only simple Class A, B or C networks are  supported.

In your example the `google-dns` entry is wrong. It's not a A,B or C network. It's an ip-address-hostname-relationship therefore it belongs to `/etc/hosts`. Actually the `default` entry is also not conformant.

Lets imagine you have an ip address `192.168.1.5` from your corporate network. An entry in `/etc/network` could then be:

```
corpname 192.168.1.0
```

When using utilities like `route` or `netstat`, those networks are translated (if you don't suppress resolution with the `-n` flag). A routing table could then look like:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
corpname        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Answer (score 8):

The `ip` command never uses a host name for input either, so your example is hardly relevant. Also you've put a host name into `/etc/networks`, not a network name!

Entries from `/etc/networks` are used by tools that try to convert numbers to names, e.g. the (deprecated) `route` command. Without a suitable entry it shows:

```
# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

If I now add a line `mylocalnet 192.168.0.0` to `/etc/networks`:

```
# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
mylocalnet      *               255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

In practice it's never really used.